# Cursor Pagination (prev / next) with null values

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I have a cursor pagination implemented with MySQL (version 8.0), which works fine as long as there are no `null` values involved.

Here's my example data (`id` is a random UUID, `date` is date, `time` is time):

```
id | date       | time
--------------------------
68 | 2017-10-28 | 22:00:00
d3 | 2017-11-03 | null
dd | 2017-11-03 | 21:45:00
62 | 2017-11-04 | 14:00:00
a1 | 2017-11-04 | 19:40:00
```

The `cursor` I use always consists of all three columns.

I use this query to get the **next** results (after the `cursor`):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (date > cursor.date)
    OR (date = cursor.date AND time > cursor.time)
    OR (date = cursor.date AND time = cursor.time AND id > cursor.id)
ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC, id ASC
```

And this query for **prev** results (before the `cursor`):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (date < cursor.date)
    OR (date = cursor.date AND time < cursor.time)
    OR (date = cursor.date AND time = cursor.time AND id < cursor.id)
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC, id DESC
```

When using the **prev** query with `cursor [id = dd, date = 2017-11-03, time = 21:45:00]` it won't return the row with `id = d3`, because `time` is `null`, and this won't get selected by `time < cursor.time`.

Though I tried using `time < cursor.time OR time IS NULL` instead of `time < cursor.time` to include rows with `null` values. Which seems to fix this particular problem, but then creates a new problem: When using the **prev** query with `cursor [id = d3, date = 2017-11-03, time = null]`, because now the result contains the row of the provided cursor.

I hope there's an easy solution for this. There seems to be no examples or tutorials on the web that deal with `null` values in cursor pagination.

**Note:** For the solution it doesn't matter if `null` will be sorted before or after `non-null` values, as long as it's consistent. (MySQL's default ordering is `null < non-null`)

Comment: Please mention the version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I'm running MySQL 8.0.26

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin M for such quick response. I have tried to find a solution with cte and row_number().

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment is very naive, but isn't it possible to use `time < cursor.time OR time IS NULL OR cursor.time IS NULL` in your query? I'm not really comfortable with cursors, but I don't know why it would not work.

Comment: @Christophe No need to be sorry. We're all here to learn new things. Your idea won't work: As I said in the question I tried using `time < cursor.time OR time IS NULL` which already selected too many rows. When you now add another `OR` condition you won't narrow down the results, but instead possibly select even more rows.

Comment: My solution was to convert the nullable columns that I wanted to use as my pagination cursors to instead be NOT NULL columns with a default value. For the text columns, I set the default to be an empty string which makes all those records appear at the top of an ascending sort, and for my datetimes, I set the default value to the oldest possible value: "1970-01-01 00:00:00" which makes them appear at the end of a descending sort. Your ability to implement this solution depends on your specific use-case of course, but this was the most elegant solution in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column to the table.  Make it a `DATETIME`.  Combine `date` and `time` into it when not NULL; combine `date` with some particular time when NULL.  Then your cursor has two columns to work with and no nulls.

If you have a reasonably recent version of MySQL, you can use a "generated stored" column, thereby avoiding any code changes.

And be sure to have `INDEX(datetime, id)`.

Comment: "generated **virtual**" would cause the same problems as the `COALESCE` solution, because values are calculated on the fly when being read. I guess you meant "generated **stored**" which calculates and **stores** the values on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. Also adding a generated stored column will trigger a table rebuild. Still looking for a query-only solution. But so far this is my preferred solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party but give the following a try. The cursor logic needs to be adjusted for nullable columns and when a cursor row returns a null value for the time column.

Both examples listed below:

```
declare @cursorID nvarchar(2)
declare @cursorDate date
declare @cursorTime time(0)


declare @table table(id nvarchar(2), date date, time time(0))
insert into @table
values
('68', '2017-10-28', '22:00:00'),
('d3', '2017-11-03', NULL),
('dd', '2017-11-03', '21:45:00'),
('62', '2017-11-04', '14:00:00'),
('a1', '2017-11-04', '19:40:00')

--IF SELECTING A ROW WITH A NON-NULL VALUE FOR TIME
set @cursorID = 'dd'
set @cursorDate = (select date from @table where id = @cursorID)
set @cursorTime = (select time from @table where id = @cursorID)

--ASCENDING CURSOR VALUES
select * from @table
where
date >= @cursorDate
and (date > @cursorDate or (time >= @cursorTime
and (time > @cursorTime or id > @cursorID)))
order by
date asc, time asc, id asc

--DESCENDING CURSOR VALUES
select * from @table
where
date <= @cursorDate
and (date < @cursorDate or ((time <= @cursorTime or time is null)
and ((time < @cursorTime or time is null) or id < @cursorID)))
order by
date desc, time desc, id desc


--IF SELECTING A ROW WITH A NON VALUE FOR TIME
set @cursorID = 'd3'
set @cursorDate = (select date from @table where id = @cursorID)
set @cursorTime = (select time from @table where id = @cursorID)

--ASCENDING CURSOR VALUES
select * from @table
where
date >= @cursorDate
and (date > @cursorDate or (time is not null
or (time is null and id > @cursorID)))
order by
date asc, time asc, id asc

--DESCENDING CURSOR VALUES
select * from @table
where
date <= @cursorDate
and (date < @cursorDate or (time is null
and (id < @cursorID)))
order by
date desc, time desc, id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to touch the topic of using cursors for pagination.  There are alternatives, such as `limit`/`offset`.

But my recommendation for your queries is to use `coalesce()`, assigning a fake time for the comparison.  MySQL makes this somewhat simple, because it supports `time` values in excess of 24 hours.  And those would not be valid values for a `date`/`time` combination.

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (date > cursor.date) OR
      (date = cursor.date AND COALESCE(time, '24:00:00') > COALESCE(cursor.time, '24:00:00')) OR
      (date = cursor.date AND COALESCE(time, '24:00:00') = COALESCE(cursor.time, '24:00:00') AND id > cursor.id)
ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC, id ASC
```

A more concise `WHERE` clause would be:

```
WHERE (date, COALESCE(time, '24:00:00'), id) > (cursor.date, COALESCE(cursor.time, '24:00:00'), cursor.id)
```

Comment: `COALESCE` looks nice and works, but it sadly defeats the purpose of cursor pagination - which is (among other things) to speed up pagination with very large `OFFSET`, by minimizing the the result set using the `WHERE` clause with indexed values. `COALESCE` won't allow index usage because the values are generated on the fly. Nevertheless this can be a useful answer for cursor pagination with small tables.

Comment: @BenjaminM . . . I might suggest updating the `NULL` times with `'24:00:00'` (or some other value) to speed up such queries.

Comment: That would imply refactoring a lot of code. I'll keep that in mind as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 then you can consider to use row_number() window funciton create an unique sequential id (rn) for each row. Then just pass the `rn` for current row to get the previous rows.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table cursortable( id varchar(10), date date, time time);

 insert into cursortable values('68' , '2017-10-28' , '22:00:00');
 insert into cursortable values('d3' , '2017-11-03' ,  null);
 insert into cursortable values('dd' , '2017-11-03' , '21:45:00');
 insert into cursortable values('62' , '2017-11-04' , '14:00:00');
 insert into cursortable values('a1' , '2017-11-04' , '19:40:00');
```

Query to get the result for fist time:

```
 select *,row_number()over(order by date,time,id)rn from cursortable
```

Output:

| id | date | time | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68 | 2017-10-28 | 22:00:00 | 1 |
| d3 | 2017-11-03 | null | 2 |
| dd | 2017-11-03 | 21:45:00 | 3 |
| 62 | 2017-11-04 | 14:00:00 | 4 |
| a1 | 2017-11-04 | 19:40:00 | 5 |

Query to get the previous rows for `cursor [id = dd, date = 2017-11-03, time = 21:45:00, rn=3]` with only `cursor [rn=3]`:

```
 with cte as
 (
   select *,row_number()over(order by date,time,id)rn from cursortable
 )
 select * from cte where rn<3
```

Output:

| id | date | time | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68 | 2017-10-28 | 22:00:00 | 1 |
| d3 | 2017-11-03 | *null* | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6bf21d5f015ecae7f4cb1aab6eb422c)*

**If you don't want to introduce an computed column into your code then please try the below solution considering all three columns `cursor [id = dd, date = 2017-11-03, time = 21:45:00]`**

Query:

```
with cte as
 (
   select *,row_number()over(order by date,time,id)rn from cursortable
 )
 ,cte2 as
 (
   select * from cte where id='dd' and date=  '2017-11-03' and time= '21:45:00'
 )
 select cte.id,cte.date,cte.time from cte inner join cte2 on cte.rn<cte2.rn
```

Output:

| id | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68 | 2017-10-28 | 22:00:00 |
| d3 | 2017-11-03 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75edf0a448153bc2d0f2f23a745b5234)*

Your code would be like below:

```
with cte as
 (
   select *,row_number()over(order by date,time,id)rn from cursortable
 )
 ,cte2 as
 (
   select * from cte where id=cursor.id and date=  cursor.date and time= cursor.time
 )
 select cte.id,cte.date,cte.time from cte inner join cte2 on cte.rn<cte2.rn
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! Some new keywords and functions I've never heard of. I'll see if I can figure it out. There's at least two additional problems to solve: `1.` When using cursor pagination, you want to utilize the db index. For example if you have classic pagination with `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10000` it will create a result set of 10010 rows and then it will throw away the first 10000 rows. That's lot's of unnecessary work and memory usage. With cursor pagination you use a complex `WHERE` clause (in combination with the db index) to create a result set that does not contain those 10000 rows.

Comment: And `2.` with cursor pagination your cursor does not have to be an existing row. You can say *"give me the first 10 rows after `[id = 00, time = 00:00:00, data: 1970-01-01]`"*. It doesn't matter if the table actually contains a row with those values. Using this feature you can insert and delete rows between multiple pagination queries and don't have to worry about duplicate rows in the returned data.

Comment: @BenjaminM It's great to know that you have got your answer. Please let me know if you tried mine. Just curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to convert the nullable columns that I wanted to use as my pagination cursors to instead be NOT NULL columns with a default value.

For the text columns, I set the default to be an empty string which makes all those records appear at the top of an ascending sort, and for my datetimes, I set the default value to the oldest possible value: "1970-01-01 00:00:00" which makes them appear at the end of a descending sort.

Then, when checking for datetime "nullness" in your app, in TS/JS it's as simple as:

```
const isNullDate = someDate <= new Date(0)
```

If your system depends on those null values, than this won't be the right solution for you, but this was the most simple/elegant/headache-reducing solution in my case.